# How do i replace Xamarin components by references (mostly Nuget packages) in a project in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, components

Visual Studio 2017 has deprecated components for Xamarin in x.Forms,x.Android and even in x.iOS. I need to replace these . The procedure is not clear to me. I did try to manually replacements but the error message persists- "Referenced components not found". I could provide more details if asked.

Comment: I would like to see the list of packages that give you this error sir!

Comment: Did you follow the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/troubleshooting/component-nuget?tabs=vswin)? If so, we'll need more details such was exactly what steps you took and full details of the errors, such as what components were not found.

Comment: Manually Look into your Proj files and Remove reference to all Components. And then you should try to find same libraries as a Nuget Package. If it exists you should add them and shouldnt get any errors. But if not you might need to change the library or try finding the code for library and add it manually inside your own project(As a different Project or Add the code files inside your own project.).

Comment: soan saini , Andrew, i took advoce from the error messages help and went to the Docs window, i followed the instructions..
1. no lines there to replace
2. because i did the Nuget Uopdate , first
3. i am listing the packages , here